# Is there a reference book that lists words by usage or theme?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, resources, cliche

Similar to how a thesaurus lists synonyms, is there a book that groups words (or phrases) together by conceptual usage?

For example, [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30369/words-used-to-describe-a-personality-trait-demeanor-or-describe-character) is looking for words that describe a person's character.  I would be interested in a book that would help me identify words commonly used to describe

- an inanimate object
- a physical motion
- nature

Ideally this would highlight what is considered a cliche description.

Comment: I would tag this question "concordance" but I don't have enough rep to create a new tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roget's Original Thesaurus was organized exactly that way. Its table of contents is organized by general theme; it is only once you traverse down to single words that he provides the set of synonyms.

Comment: +1 for [Roget's](http://poets.notredame.ac.jp/Roget/contents.html)!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you have in mind, but you might try looking for a "thematic dictionary". One that I own is "The Longman Lexicon of Contemporary English". A search for "thematic dictionary" (including the double quotes) on Google yields lots of hits.